# Adjust values of individual rows based upon order then roll up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK - Let me explain this.  I have a series of rows - the rows have a "weight" value and a "qty" and "rate" - others but am concerned with these for now... 
What I need to do is to split the rows - which I have done in the below, based on the qty - so for a row that has a qty > 1 - a row is replicated for each qty value.
So, with them all split now - I need to determine which has the highest "weight" - then I need to keep that rate at 100%.  All others will be rate/2.

Then - lastly - I need to roll the rows back up - so all like IDs are collapsed with aggregated rates - so back to single rows with sumed rates

```
/*
--create numbers table if don't already have one...
select top 1000000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
into dbo.Numbers
from   master..spt_values t1 
   cross join master..spt_values t2
*/

DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  id         int          IDENTITY(1,1) ,
  code       varchar(10)  ,
  codeStatus varchar      ,
  qty        int          ,
  rate       money        ,
  codeWeight float        ,
  comment    varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '12345' , 'T' , 3 , 375.86 , 5.6589 , NULL
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '45678' , 'T' , 2 , 2      , 4.0000 , NULL 
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '11223' , 'T' , 1 , 2      , 3.0000 , NULL 

SELECT t.id         ,
       t.code       ,
       t.qty        ,
       t.rate       ,
       t.codeWeight ,
       n.N
FROM @table      t
JOIN dbo.Numbers n on n.N <= t.qty
ORDER BY id ,
         N
```

Comment: Hey, not sure what you're trying to do with the break down & roll up - you say you detect the highest weight after splitting the rows by qty; how do you mean / why do you first split the rows before getting this?

Comment: You need to give us more: expected output, for instance. In your example, there's only 1 row with a maximum weight and given your problem statement, that's not going to change based on "splitting"/duplication of rows. Further, you don't seem to actually **do** anything with the sequence number you're applying to the duplicated rows. Please clarify your question.

Comment: The original row - before splitting - with the maximum weight - gets paid at 100%.  All other rows get paid the rate at 50%. Rows with multiple qty are "treated" like individual rows - so the original row with the highest weight gets paid at 100% - all other rows, when split out, based upon qty - get paid at 50% - in this case there would be rows with duplicate weights - but the TOP 1 I guess gets 100% and then everything else gets 50% - make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do the break down without needing the numbers table:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93b09/1

```
with cte as 
(
  SELECT id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, qty N 
  FROM myTable t 

  union all

  select id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, N - 1
  from cte
  where N > 1

)
SELECT id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, N 
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, N
```

If I've understood the next steps correctly, then this should do what you're after...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93b09/4

declare @temp table(id int, code varchar(10), qty int, rate money, codeWeight float, N int)

```
;with cte as 
(
  SELECT id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, qty N 
  FROM myTable t 

  union all

  select id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, N - 1
  from cte
  where N > 1

)
insert @temp
SELECT id, code, qty, rate, codeWeight, N 
FROM cte
ORDER BY id, N

update t
set rate = t.rate / 2.0
from @temp t
inner join myTable m on m.id = t.id
and t.qty < m.qty

select id, code, max(qty) qty, sum(rate) rate, codeWeight
from @temp
group by id, code, codeWeight
```

**Update**

Based on discussion in comments, this SQL should do everything you need:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/93b09/13

```
select id
  , code 
  , codeStatus 
  , qty 
  , case (row_number() over (order by codeWeight desc))
      when 1 then rate + case when qty > 0 then qty-1 else 0 end * rate / 2.0
      else qty * rate / 2.0
    end rate 
  , codeWeight 
  , comment
from myTable
```

i.e. the item with the greatest weight value returns a rate made up of one unit at the full rate, plus the remaining units at half price.

All other items are given rates which are their full quantity at half price.

Comment: I was trying something like the below - but it is not there.  Should be easy - order by codeWeight - highest weight gets 100% of rate - all other rows get 50% (rate/2) but am just stuck - over thinking it - somthing not tieing in the where clause or soemthing... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0fce/1

Comment: OK, so for the full quantity you want rate to be 100%, for each quantity below that the rate should be 50%?

Comment: In this example - row with '12345' should be 1*375.86 + 2*187.96
Row '45678' Should be 2 (both rows sumed at 50%)
Row '11223' should be 1 (at 50%")